# Check Conan Remote Repos with REST API

Tags: rest, artifactory, conan

I need to verify that our Conan has Artifactory set as a remote repo and make sure "ASDC-Jenkins" is the user and its using HTTPS. How would I go about starting this?

```
# Check to make sure conan compiler defined in the default profile matches system compiler
CONAN_COMPILER=`conan profile show default | grep 'compiler.version'| awk '{print $2}'`
if [ $ID = "OSX" ] ; then 
    CLANG_VERSION=`clang -v 2>&1 | grep version | sed 's/.*version \([0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*\) .*/\1/g'`
    if [ ! $CONAN_COMPILER = $CLANG_VERSION ] ; then 
        echo "WARNING:  The compiler version in the conan default profile does not match the one the system reports"
    fi
fi
if [ $ID = "Linux" ] ; then 
    if [ ! $CONAN_COMPILER = $COMPILERVER ] ; then 
        echo "WARNING:  The compiler version in the conan default profile does not match the one the system reports"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the code. You ask about checking Artifactory as remote. This can be shown in the ``conan remote list``. Most likely you are interested in the ``conan config install`` feature, that allows to configure remotes in conan clients, so all developers and CI machines share the same configuration. Regarding the user, the command ``conan user`` will display the current user for each defined remote. Please tell me if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that does help. Where can I find the information on "conan user" command and others like it? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

For the first item you need to run the following command:

```
$ conan remote list
```

Instead of `profile show` Check the [conan remote reference](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/remote.html)

Also, as a hint, instead of checking it, you can also define the remotes from a shared configuration with the command:

```
$ conan config install <url or git repo>
```

This will install in conan clients remotes, profiles, and other configuration, to make sure all developers and CI machines share the same configuration

For getting the user, you need the command:

```
$ conan user
```

It will display currently active users per remote. Check the [reference here](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/user.html)